# Separate Google Maps JS file will not load in HTML file

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-maps-api-2

I am using Google Maps API to load a map with draggable directions. It works fine and great when I have the javascript written out in the html file, but I am still adding functions and for readability's sake. Therefore, I decided to separate the two. What I got was this:

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="../CSS/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Create Route</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXX" defer></script>
<script src="../JavaScript/create_route_map.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<td>
<div id="map_canvas" name="map_canvas"></div>
</td>
<td>
<input size="25" id="hometown" type="text">
<input type = "button" value="Get Directions" onclick="calcRoute();">
</td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var rendererOptions = {
    draggable: true
};
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initMap() {

  var town = new google.maps.LatLng(46.8133,-100.7790);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: town,
    zoom: 7
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.GetElementByID('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function(){
    computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
    });

calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute() {
  var start = "Town"
  var end = document.getElementById('hometown').value;
  var request = {
      origin:start,
      destination:end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initmap);
```

I've tried using the function loadscript() but that didn't work.

```
function loadScript() {
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.type = 'text/javascript';
 script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXX' +
  'callback=initMap';
 document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

I've also tried removing the api key since it is no longer needed for v3, but that didn't work either.

Thoughts? Suggestions? What am I missing?

(I think an important side note is that the .css file includes the height and width for the map-canvas div.)

**UPDATE**
After retyping getElementById and placing the scripts above , the errors I'm getting from the browser console are:
ReferenceError: google is not defined
NetworkError: A network error occurred

How would I go about fixing the Reference Error?

Comment: Move them to the bottom of your page, just before the `</body>` tag, maybe?

Comment: @Frondor I tried to do that, but it didn't work either.

Comment: What is the error in the browser console?

Comment: @Seano666 
ReferenceError: initmap is not defined 
TypeError: document.GetElementByID is not a function

Comment: it is `document.getElementById`
I think it is only a syntax error, you used the capital G inside the `initMap` function

Comment: @lecya I changed that, but it still didn't work. I'm still getting that error in the console.

Comment: Ok, so I retyped both 'document.getElementById'  that existed in my JavaScript, and now that error isn't there - so that worked. Thanks, @lecya.
However, it still isn't loading. I had to change the 'defer' to 'async' to get an error to populate and I got "ReferenceError: google is not defined". Thoughts?

Comment: did you put the `loadScript()` (or whatever call the `initMap` function) AFTER your js code..? If you call a function that is not loaded yet it will be undefined...

Comment: can you provide a live example?

Comment: @lecya I put loadScript() after initMap(). I tried it again, and again, I'm not getting any errors, just a blank screen with my text box and button. 
And, this is a little embarrassing, but I don't know if I know what a live example is - if I did I'd be more than happy to provide one.

Comment: a live example is a working online page that reproduce your issue. Or if you can link the website you are working on

Comment: @lecya I can't provide one - or at least from what I understand. I'm building this for a class so it's locally hosted. (Did I understand correctly?)